# idea не работают методы из deeplearning4j

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deeplearning4j

При помощи gradle в Java проект в Intellij Ide добавил зависимости для deeplearning4j. Вот мой файл build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'vladf'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version: '1.0.0-beta'
    compile group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta'
    compile group: 'org.datavec', name: 'datavec-api', version: '1.0.0-beta'
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25"
}
```

Я написал следующий код:

```
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.nd4j.linalg.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        final String SIMPLE_FUNCTIONAL_MLP = new ClassPathResource("modelimport/keras/simple_functional_mlp.h5").getFile().getPath();
        MultiLayerNetwork model = new KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(SIMPLE_FUNCTIONAL_MLP);
    }
}
```

Среда всё нормально определяет, но вот метод KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights() подсвечивается как ошибка, хотя Idea сама предлагает использовать его при автозаполнении. При наведении на ошибку появляется сообщение `Cannot resolve symbol 'importKerasModelAndWeights'`. С другой стороны, я могу нажать на класс KerasModelImport и увидеть, что в нём есть метод (несколько, если учесть переопределение) `importKerasModelAndWeights`, тот метод, который мне и нужен. Как я могу исправить эту проблему?

**UPD1:**

```
MultiLayerNetwork model_ = new MultiLayerNetwork(new MultiLayerConfiguration());
```

Этот код работает нормально, без ошибок, хоть и использует эту либу

Answer (score 0):

Идёт вызов метода, но зачем-то я написал new. Надо так:

```
MultiLayerNetwork model = KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(SIMPLE_FUNCTIONAL_MLP);
```